# Action when unclick outside a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Beginner question incoming:

I have a kind-of popup window, a div class hiddenW, which is displayed when you click on a button. Thanks to a bit of code i found, when you click outside the div, it is hidden.

The problem is when you click in the div BUT unclick OUTSIDE the div, the action is taken into account and the div is hidden which I want to avoid.

This is needed when the user wants to select and delete the text in the input (for example.)
His "unclick" action is rarely inside the div.

```js
$(document).click(function(e) 
        {
            var container = $(".hiddenW");
            if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0 && e.target.id != "startButton") 
            {
                container.hide();
            }
        });


        function display() {
            $(".hiddenW").show();
        }
```

```css
.hiddenW {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            width: 25%;
            min-width: 400px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 3px solid blue;
            background-color: white;

            border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            display: none;

            display: relative;
            z-index: 100;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        input {
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <button id="startButton" onclick="display()">SHOW</button>

    <div class="hiddenW">
        
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" value="bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla "/>

    </div>
```

Any idea how could I avoid that?

Thanks a lot.
F

Comment: There is no such thing as "unclick". Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: How do you call the action when you release the click from your mouse?

Comment: That would be the [`mouseup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event) event.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a div that creates behind your popup and put the click event on that background div and not document.
Also make sure to not put the pop-up div inside the background div. This would triger event propagation.

Have a read about event bubbling aswell, it will help you to understand how DOM handles events.